# How to link google analytics property to bigQuery using an api?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I want to export google analytics data to bigquery to run some queries on user_id. For that i want to programmatically link ga4 property to bigquery. I am not able to find an api for that, is that possible? If not, is there a way to download raw data from ga and then i can create the schema manually in bigexport.

Comment: There is a built-in GA4 to BQ data flow you can easily enable. Have a look at the GA4BigQuery website. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: Yes so my project lets users build their websites and configure ga from ui. Hence i create ga4 properties from my backend for each such websites and now i want to link those properties to bigquery programmatically

Comment: So could you not set up the automatic data flow for each property into BQ at property create time? That will automatically give you raw event level data and also now raw user level data.

Comment: That is exactly what i want to do but ga4 does'nt provide any api to do it based on what i found. ([reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/properties.bigQueryLinks))

Comment: Are you saying uou are creating the properties via an api?

Comment: yes and i would like to link those properties to bigquery via api as well

Comment: OK got it, sorry